# How can I display/render data from mongoose model to ejs file

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am new to programming. I have a mongoose model called 'RestInput'.I am trying to figure out how to render and display info in a .ejs file using mongoose.

in the app.js

```
router.get('/find',(req,res) => {
  RestInput.find({}, function(err,data) { 
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.send(500).status;
    }
    else {
        res.render('find.ejs', {data : data});
        }            
  });
});
```

in the RestSchema.js

```
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var restaurant = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  location: String,
  phone: Number

});
module.exports = mongoose.model("RestInput", restaurant);
```

in my .ejs file

```
 <% data.forEach(function (items) { %>
        <td> <%= items.name %> </td>
        <td> <%= items.description %> </td>
        <td> <%= items.location %> </td>
        <td> <%= items.phone %> </td>
      <% }) %>  
     </tr>
```

The data are saved succesfully but when i try to access my ejs file i get an error saying that data is not defined.

I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: I don't see any reason for that code will throw that error. What it will be the output in the console for the data if you'll print it?

Comment: It's not necessary to add the ejs file termination. The errors are not handled properly. You can use the next function for that or ex: res.status(500).send(err.message);

Comment: When i display the data , the phone attribute doesnt appear. I don't know why would that happen. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Dta</th>
</tr>
//Here I used variableName as Variable
<% for (var i = 0; i < variable.length; i++) { %>
<tr>
  <td><%= variable[i].name %></td>
  <td><%= variable[i].description %></td>
  <td><%= variable[i].location %></td>
  <td><%= variable[i].phone %></td>
</tr>    
<% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: I did that but phone attribute still doesn't appear. It seems that this specific attribute doesn't save at all in the database.

Comment: Did you create an instance of your Schema? If you create an instance like `const restaurant =  new Restaurant` then you need to pass `res.render('find.ejs', {'data' : req.restaurant});` and in your ejs file try to access value like  `<%= data.name %>` and access another value also `<%=  data.phone % >`

Comment: Yes i have this: var myData = new RestInput(req.body), that i use in my .save() method.

Comment: Then you need to pass this`myData` into your `app.js` file like this inside into your `GET` routes in `else` replace with this line  `res.render('find.ejs', {'data' : req.myData});` and in your `ejs` file  try to access the value like `<=% data.phone %>`